# Transfering files into S3 buckets based on Glue job status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

```
 I am new to **AWS Glue,** and my aim is to extract  transform and load files uploaded in S3 bucket to RDS instance. Also I need to transfer the files into separate S3 buckets based on the Glue Job status (Success /Failure). There will be more than one file uploaded into the initial S3 bucket. How can I get the name of the files uploaded so that i can transfer those files to appropriate buckets.
```

Step 1: Upload files to S3 bucket1.
Step 2: Trigger lamda function to call Job1
Step 3: On success of job1 transfer file to S3 bucket2
Step 4: On failure transfer to another S3 bucket

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can I get the file name in cloudwatch event ? The thing is that there can be a FTP server that will push files to S3 bucket. So for every file addition job will trigger. In cloud watch event I need the processed file name.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#glue-event-types - yes its possible to get the job name

Comment: If the job is successful, will I get the file name that is uploaded in S3?,which is responsible for the job to trigger. We can send file name as job parameter to glue job from lamda function. Is there any  way to send the particular file name to the cloud watch event the looks for the job status(Success/Failure).

Comment: I haven't tried such scenario, as i didn't have such a requirement.  Would suggest you to accept the answer if its helpful, and then explore the glue APIs to suit your needs.

Comment: I checked many ways but I didn't got a better solution. The answer you gave is helpful, but I need the file name too.. I tried this with lamda function, where I checked the status of the executing job in a loop, and when the status changed I could transfer the file. But will it be cost effective? Because my lamda function is executing till the job finishes its execution.

Comment: you cannot chk the glue job status in lambda, due to the reason the lambda has a max time limit of 15 minutes.  The best way is to handle/check the glue job status would be the cloudwatch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any provision to identify the processed files in s3 bucket (Those files which has underwent  transformation through glue job)?

Comment: As i mentioned in my previous comment, please do some exploration from your end, not just asking more questions, and let us know if you are facing any issue.  We can assist you and direct you to some direction.

Comment: I could resolve the issue. it worked. It was an issue with the account that I used. If I use root user then everything is fine.. thanks for all your comments.

Comment: glad you have resolved the issue, and good to hear the comments were useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a lambda event trigger listening to the folder you are uploading
   the files to S3 In the lambda, use AWS Glue API to run the glue job
   (essentially a python script in AWS Glue).

In Glue python script, use the appropriate library, such as pymysql, etc. 
   as an external library packaged with your python script.

Perform data load operations from S3 to your RDS tables.  If you are 
   using Aurora Mysql, then AWS has provided a nice feature 
   "load from S3", so you can directly load the
   file into the tables (you may need to do some configurations in the
   PARAMETER GROUP / IAM Roles).

### Lambda script to call glue job:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
glue = boto3.client('glue')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    gluejobname="<YOUR GLUE JOB NAME>"

    try:
        runId = glue.start_job_run(JobName=gluejobname)
        status = glue.get_job_run(JobName=gluejobname, RunId=runId['JobRunId'])
        print("Job Status : ", status['JobRun']['JobRunState'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    raise e
```

### Glue Script:

```
import mysql.connector
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.context import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.transforms import *
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp, from_unixtime
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

# Create a Glue context
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

url="<RDS URL>"
uname="<USER NAME>"
pwd="<PASSWORD>"
dbase="DBNAME"


def connect():
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=url, user=uname, password=pwd, database=dbase)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    return cur, conn

def create_stg_table():
    cur, conn = connect()
    createStgTable1 = <CREATE STAGING TABLE IF REQUIRED>

    loadQry = "LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX 'S3://PATH FOR YOUR CSV' REPLACE INTO TABLE <DB.TABLENAME> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (@var1, @var2, @var3, @var4, @var5, @var6, @var7, @var8) SET ......;"
    cur.execute(createStgTable1)
    cur.execute(loadQry)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

You can then create a cloudwatch alert wherein check for the glue job status, and depending upon the status, perform file copy operations between S3.  We have similar setup in our production.

Regards

Yuva